# How to collect values from a channel into a slice in Go?

Tags: go

Suppose I have a helper function `helper(n int)` which returns a slice of integers of variable length. I would like to run `helper(n)` in parallel for various values of `n` and collect the output in one big slice. My first attempt at this is the following:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func main() {
    out := make([]int, 0)
    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for i := range ch {
            out = append(out, i)
        }
    }()

    g := new(errgroup.Group)
    for n := 2; n <= 3; n++ {
        n := n
        g.Go(func() error {
            for _, i := range helper(n) {
                ch <- i
            }
            return nil
        })
    }
    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    close(ch)

    // time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(out) // should have the same elements as [0 1 0 1 2]
}

func helper(n int) []int {
    out := make([]int, 0)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        out = append(out, i)
    }
    return out
}
```

However, if I run this example I do not get all 5 expected values, instead I get

```
[0 1 0 1]
```

(If I uncomment the `time.Sleep` I do get all five values, `[0 1 2 0 1]`, but this is not an acceptable solution).

It seems that the problem with this is that `out` is being updated in a goroutine, but the `main` function returns before it is done updating.

One thing that would work is using a buffered channel of size 5:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 5)

    g := new(errgroup.Group)
    for n := 2; n <= 3; n++ {
        n := n
        g.Go(func() error {
            for _, i := range helper(n) {
                ch <- i
            }
            return nil
        })
    }
    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    close(ch)

    out := make([]int, 0)
    for i := range ch {
        out = append(out, i)
    }

    fmt.Println(out) // should have the same elements as [0 1 0 1 2]
}
```

However, although in this simplified example I know what the size of the output should be, in my actual application this is not known a priori. Essentially what I would like is an 'infinite' buffer such that sending to the channel never blocks, or a more idiomatic way to achieve the same thing; I've read https://blog.golang.org/pipelines but wasn't able to find a close match to my use case. Any ideas?

Comment: the first code must synchronize the range over ch and the print of out. Otherwise it is undefined. The code did produce `[0 1 2 0 1]`, numbers are here, but their ordering is undefined. The second code is fragile imho because it relies on a buffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this version of the code, the execution is blocked until `ch` is closed.

`ch` is always closed at the end of a routine that is responsible to push into `ch`. Because the program pushes to `ch` in a routine, it is not needed to use a buffered channel.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        g := new(errgroup.Group)
        for n := 2; n <= 3; n++ {
            n := n
            g.Go(func() error {
                for _, i := range helper(n) {
                    ch <- i
                }
                return nil
            })
        }
        if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        close(ch)
    }()

    out := make([]int, 0)
    for i := range ch {
        out = append(out, i)
    }

    fmt.Println(out) // should have the same elements as [0 1 0 1 2]
}

func helper(n int) []int {
    out := make([]int, 0)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        out = append(out, i)
    }
    return out
}
```

Here is the fixed version of the first code, it is convoluted but demonstrates the usage of `sync.WaitGroup`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"

    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func main() {
    out := make([]int, 0)
    ch := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := range ch {
            out = append(out, i)
        }
    }()

    g := new(errgroup.Group)
    for n := 2; n <= 3; n++ {
        n := n
        g.Go(func() error {
            for _, i := range helper(n) {
                ch <- i
            }
            return nil
        })
    }
    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    close(ch)

    wg.Wait()
    // time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(out) // should have the same elements as [0 1 0 1 2]
}

func helper(n int) []int {
    out := make([]int, 0)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        out = append(out, i)
    }
    return out
}
```